# Spray Authentication method with BasicAuth

Tags: scala, spray

Spray is hard!! I now know that my knowledge on HTTP protocol is not nearly enough and API design isn't easy. However, I still very much want my practice app to work. I'm writing this authentication for `POST/PUT/DELETE` method. It appears that there are at least two ways to do this: `BasicAuth` or write a custom directive.

I found this article:

BasicAuth: https://github.com/jacobus/s4/blob/master/src/main/scala/s4/rest/S4Service.scala

I'm trying it out because it looks simple.

The compile and run stages are fine, and the server runs. However, when I'm trying to send a PUT request to test the implementation (using Python's Httpie: `http PUT 127.0.0.1:8080/sec-company/casper username=username token=123`), the feedback is:`HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found`

Here's my route:

```
pathPrefix("sec-company") {
        path("casper") {
          //first examine username and token
          authenticate(BasicAuth(CustomUserPassAuthenticator, "company-security")) {userProfile =>
            post { ctx =>
              entity(as[Company.Company]) { company =>
                complete {
                  company
                }
              }
            }
   }
```

Here is my implementation of `UserPassAuthenticator`:

```
object CustomUserPassAuthenticator extends UserPassAuthenticator[UserProfile] {
    def apply(userPass: Option[UserPass]) = Promise.successful(
      userPass match {
        case Some(UserPass(user, token)) => getUserProfile(user, token)
        case _ => None
      }
    ).future
  }
```

First of all, is this the right way to implement authentication? Second, where does `UserPassAuthenticator` find the username and password?? Can I send back a better HTTP header other than `404` to indicate failed authentication?

If this is far from correct, is there any tutorial on authentication that I can follow? TypeSafe's Spray templates are more about overall patterns and less about Spray's functionality!

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same problem, even after looking at https://github.com/spray/spray/wiki/Authentication-Authorization (which says it's for an older version of Akka but it still seems to apply) I came up with the following:

```
trait Authenticator {
  def basicUserAuthenticator(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): AuthMagnet[AuthInfo] = {
    def validateUser(userPass: Option[UserPass]): Option[AuthInfo] = {
      for {
        p <- userPass
        user <- Repository.apiUsers(p.user)
        if user.passwordMatches(p.pass)
      } yield AuthInfo(user)
    }

    def authenticator(userPass: Option[UserPass]): Future[Option[AuthInfo]] = Future { validateUser(userPass) }

    BasicAuth(authenticator _, realm = "Private API")
  }
}
```

I mix in this trait into the Actor that runs the routes and then I call it like this:

```
runRoute(
  pathPrefix("api") {
    authenticate(basicUserAuthenticator) { authInfo =>
      path("private") {
        get {
          authorize(authInfo.hasPermission("get") {
            // ... and so on and so forth
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The `AuthInfo` object returned by the `validateUser` method is passed as a parameter to the closure given to the `authorize` method. Here it is:

```
case class AuthInfo(user: ApiUser) {
  def hasPermission(permission: String) = user.hasPermission(permission)
}
```

In Spray (and HTTP), authentication (determining whether you have a valid user) is separate from authorization (determining whether the user has access to a resource). In the `ApiUser` class I also store the set of permissions the user has. This is a simplified version, my hasPermission method is a bit more complex since I also parametrize permissions, so it's not just that a particular user has permission to do a get on a resource, he might have permission to read only some parts of that resource. You might make things very simple (any logged-in user can access any resource) or extremely complex, depending on your needs.

As to your question, when using HTTP BASIC authentication (the `BasicAuth` object), the credentials are passed in the request in an `Authorization:` header. Your HTTP library should take care of generating that for you. According to the HTTP standard, the server should return a 401 status code if the authentication was incorrect or not provided, or a 403 status code if the authentication was correct but the user doesn't have permissions to view the content.

Comment: `Repository.apiUsers(login: String)` is how I get my User object from my database given their login. In your case you would need to go to the DB or wherever you're storing your users' credentials and get it from there. `user.passwordMatches` is a method in my User class that verifies whether the given password matches the user's password (since it's stored hashed and salted). I hope that's clear!

Comment: Thank you so much! That's much clearer. But what should `AuthInfo` look like? How can I also give user the opportunity to send username&password (or just an authentication token) from POST body or GET query?

Comment: I missed that... I've edited the answer to add info about `AuthInfo`. Now that I look at it, I should really turn this into a blog post :)

Comment: You should and post the link here! I'll read it! This is a really important topic. Btw, I tried this solution, but this way, if authen failed, Spray doesn't return `401` response, and you have to do it by yourself using `complete(401, "failed")`

Comment: Here's the post. Enjoy :) http://mcamou.github.io/blog/2014/07/07/implementing-http-basic-authentication-with-spray/